# What to return if a controller cannot be found?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-controller

I just encountered an error in an MVC app I'm building because the browser requested /favicon.ico which matches a route, but for which there is no controller.

What is the recommended way of handling a controller request such as this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm, I should've looked a bit further before asking: [Custom Controller Factory, Dependency Injection / Structuremap problems with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719678/custom-controller-factory-dependency-injection-structuremap-problems-with-asp)

A simple 'ignore route' entry will do the trick.

Comment: Don't forget to checkmark your answer as the correct answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I will. But I can't until 2 days have passed :)